# Importing and pivoting multiple CSV files and embedding as variable in data table

Tags: r, csv

I need to import multiple csv files each containing 2 columns - wavenumber and intensity, but no headers. Each file contains the same wavelengths. The code below imports the files as a list of dataframes, keeping the original column structure.

However, I would like to pivot_wide each file so that columns are individual wavenumbers and intensity is the value, but I have not seen anyone pivoting in a for loop.

Finally, I would like to construct a data table in which the pivoted spectral data is embedded in one variable. The aim is something similar to the NIRsoil data in the *prospectr* package, or the gasoline data in the *pls* package.

````
myfiles = lapply(temp, read.csv, sep = ",", colClasses = c("numeric", "numeric"), header = FALSE, col.names = c("wavenumber", "absorbance"))```
````

Comment: Please add data using `dput` and show the expected output for the same. Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can make a toy example of the `myfiles` data structure like this:

```r
df_maker <- function(x){
  data.frame(wavenumber = 2^(6:10), absorbance = round(runif(5), 3))
}

set.seed(69)
myfiles <- lapply(1:3, df_maker)
```

So we have a list of two-column data frames containing matching values of `wavenumber` but different values for `absorbance` as described in the question:

```
myfiles
#> [[1]]
#>   wavenumber absorbance
#> 1         64      0.531
#> 2        128      0.769
#> 3        256      0.646
#> 4        512      0.865
#> 5       1024      0.369
#> 
#> [[2]]
#>   wavenumber absorbance
#> 1         64      0.869
#> 2        128      0.171
#> 3        256      0.788
#> 4        512      0.174
#> 5       1024      0.022
#> 
#> [[3]]
#>   wavenumber absorbance
#> 1         64      0.883
#> 2        128      0.357
#> 3        256      0.926
#> 4        512      0.260
#> 5       1024      0.183
```

The idea is that we want to transform this structure into a data frame where the columns are the wavelengths, with one row for each file. We can do this by using `lapply` to pick out the `absorbance` vectors and `rbind` them together into a matrix. We then name the columns of the matrix according to the `wavelength` column of the first file. Finally, we convert to a data frame, adding a `file_number` column so we can keep track of where each observation came from:

```
values <- do.call(rbind, lapply(myfiles, function(x) x$absorbance))
values <- `colnames<-`(values, paste0("lambda_", myfiles[[1]]$wavenumber))
df     <- data.frame(file_number = seq(nrow(values)), values)
```

So the final result looks like this:

```
df
#>   file_number lambda_64 lambda_128 lambda_256 lambda_512 lambda_1024
#> 1           1     0.531      0.769      0.646      0.865       0.369
#> 2           2     0.869      0.171      0.788      0.174       0.022
#> 3           3     0.883      0.357      0.926      0.260       0.183
```

<sup>Created on 2020-07-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>